# service got stopped when the app goes background

Tags: android, service, signalr, android-service

Hi in project I'm using service for chat communication using SignalR. Chat communication is working fine but when the app goes to background the service got stopped I need to run the services fully till my app get deleted

Here is me service code

```
public class SignalRService extends Service {
private HubConnection mHubConnection;
private HubProxy mHubProxy;
private Handler mHandler; // to display Toast message
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder(); // Binder given to clients

public SignalRService() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    int result = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    startSignalR();
    return result;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("onDestroy","onDestroy");
    mHubConnection.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Return the communication channel to the service.
    startSignalR();
    return mBinder;
}

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public SignalRService getService() {
        // Return this instance of SignalRService so clients can call public methods
        return SignalRService.this;
    }
}

/**
 * method for clients (activities)
 */
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    String SERVER_METHOD_SEND = "Send";
    mHubProxy.invoke(SERVER_METHOD_SEND, message);
}

/**
 * method for clients (activities)
 */
public void sendMessage_To(String receiverName, String message) {
    String SERVER_METHOD_SEND_TO = "SendChatMessage";
    mHubProxy.invoke(SERVER_METHOD_SEND_TO, receiverName, message);
}

private void startSignalR() {
    Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
    Credentials credentials = new Credentials() {
        @Override
        public void prepareRequest(Request request) {
            request.addHeader("User-Name", "BNK");
        }
    };

    String serverUrl = "http://10.10.10.180/signalr/hubs";
    mHubConnection = new HubConnection(serverUrl);
    mHubConnection.setCredentials(credentials);
    String SERVER_HUB_CHAT = "ChatHub";
    mHubProxy = mHubConnection.createHubProxy(SERVER_HUB_CHAT);
    ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mHubConnection.getLogger());
    SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = mHubConnection.start(clientTransport);

    try {
        signalRFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        Log.e("SimpleSignalR", e.toString());
        return;
    }

    sendMessage("Hello from BNK!");

    String CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE = "broadcastMessage";
    mHubProxy.on(CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE,
            new SubscriptionHandler1<CustomMessage>() {
                @Override
                public void run(final CustomMessage msg) {
                    final String finalMsg = msg.UserName + " says " + msg.Message;
                    // display Toast message
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.i("message","message: "+finalMsg);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), finalMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            , CustomMessage.class);
}}
```

And here is the activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final Context mContext = this;
private SignalRService mService;
private boolean mBound = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(mContext, SignalRService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // Unbind from the service
    Log.i("onStop","onStop");
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
    super.onStop();
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    if (mBound) {
        // Call a method from the SignalRService.
        // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
        // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        EditText editText_Receiver = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_receiver);
        if (editText != null && editText.getText().length() > 0) {
            String receiver = editText_Receiver.getText().toString();
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            mService.sendMessage_To(receiver, message);
            mService.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService()
 */
private final ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to SignalRService, cast the IBinder and get SignalRService instance
        SignalRService.LocalBinder binder = (SignalRService.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {

        Log.i("onServiceDisconnected","onServiceDisconnected");

        mBound = false;
    }
};}
```

My manifest code for service

```
<service
        android:name=".SignalRService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
```

Plese help me on this

Answer (score 1):

If you bind the service with any component the system will automatically destroy the service if no other client is bound with it.

If you want to run a service independently then you have to start a service rather than bind. But you can't communicate with a service if you start it with `startService()`

For more details you can see the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: if I remove unbindService(mConnection); from the onStop app is getting crashed

Comment: can you provide me any sample for this type of service bcz I'm new to services

Comment: I need to do   client-server interface can i do it on startService() method

Comment: I achieved the same functionality using BroadcastReceiver, though I know it is not the best solution. But some how I managed to work it for me. You may try this. :)

Comment: Do you have that type of sample code so I can also try it? I can't figure it out

Comment: I don't have it now. I can share you my workflow.
Register two BroadcastReceiver. One in your service class, other in your Activity class. Now start the service from activity and register receivers in your onCreate methods. Now pass the data through the broadcast intent when you need. Also stop the service through broadcast intent. For details about broadcast please see the broadcast documentation.

Comment: You can also get a proper direction to implementing such service in  https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Answer (score 0):

**You can BOTH start AND bind the service.**

In this way, even if multiple components bind to the service at once, then ALL of them unbind, the service will **NOT** be destroyed. Refer to [A service can essentially take two forms: Bound](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

> your service can work both ways: it can be started (to run indefinitely) and also allow binding. It's simply a matter of whether you implement a couple callback methods: onStartCommand() to allow components to start it and onBind() to allow binding.

```
// onBind method just return the IBinder, to allow clients to get service.
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

// onStartCommand just return START_STICKY to let system to
// try to re-create the service if the servcie's process is killed.
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

// and make startSignalR public to allow client to call this method.
public void startSignalR() {
}
```

In your clients, no need to keep a boolean `mBound`.

Just bind service when `onCreate`, unbind service when `onDestroy`. DO NOT unbind when `onStop`. Since `onStop` may called many times, for example dialog popup will invoke `onStop`, but your activity is still on foreground, this will cause your service destroyed.

Refer to [my answer for question: Pass Service From one Activity to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38847374/2722270) for sample code.